# Upper bound for chromatic number ($\chi(G) \leq \Delta(G)+1$)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

i am new in graph theory. I saw in some text book this "obvious" upper bound $$\chi(G) \leq \Delta(G)+1$$ i can't see how to demonstrate it

Comment: It is also worth noticing that this bound is known as Brooks's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $k$ colors where $k$  is one larger than the maximal degree, Order the vertices arbitrarily, and color them one by one in this order; for each vertex use a color that has not been used for any of its previously colored neighbors.